# DailyRollingLog doesn't works in spring mvc

Tags: spring, log4j

I am trying to achieve daily rolling log using log4j in  my spring application. Here is the code i have tried,

Pom.xml

```
<!-- Log4j -->
<dependency>
<groupId>log4j</groupId>
<artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
<version>1.2.17</version>
```

logback.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <appender name="RollingAppender" class="org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender">
       <param name="File" value="${catalina.home}/logs/app.log" />
       <param name="DatePattern" value="'.'yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm" />
       <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout"> 
          <param name="ConversionPattern" value="[%p] %d %c %M - %m%n"/>           
       </layout>  
    </appender>

    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <encoder> 
      <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
  </appender> 

    <logger name="org.springframework" level="DEBUG"/>
  <root level="DEBUG">
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
  </root>

</configuration>
```

I have placed the **logback.xml** file under **/WEB-INF/classes**

Here i have tested the xml logics takes a log rolling file in every minutes. If this works then i can modify the **DatePattern** to **"'.'yyyy-MM-dd"**

But Its doesnt works out.

Where am i doing mistake?

Even I have tried log4j.properties file like below,

```
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, loggerId  
log4j.appender.loggerId=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender  
log4j.appender.loggerId.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.loggerId.File=D:\\examples\\logfile.log
log4j.appender.loggerId.DatePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd-hh-mm  
log4j.appender.loggerId.layout.ConversionPattern=%d [%t] %-5p (%F:%L) - %m%n
```

But still its not taking log file for every minutes !!

Answer (score 0):

logback and log4j are totally different things.

You have to use logback jar with logback.xml, or log4j jar with log4j properties.

Comment: Ok you are right. but pls check my updated question.

Comment: @MMMMS  did it create the log file,?did the log info written in the file?

Comment: No. I dont see any file in that location.